# Game for DirectX 9 not working with DirectX 11

Tags: windows-7, directx

I have installed a game called "Orcs Must Die" but when running it, it only shows an error about absence of d3dx9_43.dll file. It's part of DX 9, however I hava already DX 11 installed. How can I solve this problem without coming back to DX 9?

I'm using Win7 Home Preemium 32-bit, DirectX 11, nVidia GeForce Go 7300 (drivers v295.73)

Comment: Which game is it?

Comment: @burtek - You need to install DirectX. The game is looking for a DirectX 9 file, which means until you provide it that file, you won't be able to run the game. Besides just because you have DirectX 11 installed, doesn't mean the game supports DirectX 11, the game no matter what you do is still only going to support Direct X 9.

Comment: @aliasgar Edited the question. Sorry, forgot to add it earlier

Comment: @Ramhound so I have to install DirectX9? Is it possible to have both v9 and v11 installed at the same time?

Comment: @burtek - Yes. You can have multiple versions of DirectX 9 installed. Steam installs the required version of for the given game you are trying to play. Its difficult to explain the Direct X 9 backwards support that exists in Direct X 11 to a non-developer.  It basically amounts to the developer using the Direct 11.0/11.1 library and writting code to support the previous versions.  Orcs Must Die is only supports Direct X 9.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Orcs Must Die totally supports DirectX 11. Gamers have confirmed it working:  [Read More Here](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2162262)
- Its your DirectX that is malfunctioning due to some reason. Microsoft has also logged it. Follow the instructions [Here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-gaming/directx-install-for-orcs-must-die-fails/cb998628-b0f1-4002-b7da-24fdea78aba4?msgId=eb75b1c7-300e-47ff-9760-547b9a649b42) to fix it.
- Check if your nVidia driver is over-riding any DirectX settings.
- Test your system if the game can actually run and ur system can handle it [Here](http://www.systemrequirementslab.com/cyri/)

Comment: It does not really matter if Orcs Must Die supports Direct X 11 it still is a Direct X 9 game.  Which means it doesn't really matter how its run, it will look exactly the same, no matter what version is used.  Based on the research I found Orcs Must Die was not on a character that listed every game that supported Direct X 11 and soon to be released game that supports it.  This chart also listed the other version the game supported.  Orcs Must Die was absent from this list.

Comment: @Ramhound Even if its a Direct X 9 game, people have reported it works on Windows 7 with a higher version of Direct X. His problem is, is that the game itself throws an exception and doesn't start.

Comment: @aliagar - I can't follow the link you posted.  My guess those people actually have Direct X 9 installed.  My statements about how the backwards support works is still true of course.

Comment: @Ramhound the link is good, maybe your in office or something. Most of them said they have Direct X 11 , windows 7 and a higher end Graphics Card.

Comment: @aliasgar - I never said the link it didn't work.  I just said I cannot visit it.  Even if I did visit the link, my conclusion on what the user's had installed would not change, the people who claim it works also had Direct X 9 installed.  The game in question cannot be run as a Direct X 11 game.

Comment: @Ramhound, sorry mis-read. Yes, u maybe correct, but I really don't intend in having a rage war over all our questions and answers.

Comment: This is long way too;)

Answer (score 8):

DirectX installs can co-exist. So it should be safe to install dx9 when dx11 is already installed.

You could also download a dll-pack, which might include the one you're missing. [Download here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8109)

Comment: nice find .. +1

Comment: Not so nice) You'll download all packs (maybe GBs), and find there the missing file. But I'll download the missing dll (~2MB) and my game will run perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

It means that game also uses DX9 DLLs. Developers use new DX libraries (especially for new effects), but bad developers are partially using DirectX 9 and they simply don't want to leave it.

Probably you've started finding DirectX packs now.
There's no need to find all files in CDs, DirectX packs, and so on.
You can download the missing file from the net, and place it `on game's executable's folder` 
(or in System32 or 64, but do this if nothing helps).
For example you can download your missing d3dx9_43 file **[here](http://www.dll-files.com/dllindex/dll-files.shtml?d3dx9_43)**.

Answer (score 0):

i had that issue with DAO, d3dx9_36.dll missing, this Microsoft DX installer helped me
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35
it installs the missing DX9 components, it is good for issues like this.

its just that i installed DAO & DA2 back cause there is DA3 coming out, back, but in to new PC, this PC has never had Dragon Age in it before.